# Custom Taxonomies options are not showing up on Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress project, and using a **wordpress-meta-data-taxonomies-filter-wordpress-plugin**. By default there are two filters showing up in sidebar, which works fine, but when I add more options in the Taxonomies then they doesn't work properly.

Please take a look at attached images:

**Frontend View:**

[image]

**Admin View:**

[image]

Comment: do you have records in taxonomies?

Comment: @Noman yes, there are records